# node js updating post request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I am sending request from form (using Angularjs) to create new user. It works and inserts data in my collection. But how i manage to update my data on backend part using node js express. For example i want to check if username is free. I am trying to console.log something when i send post request. But nothing is logging.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const restify = require('express-restify-mongoose');
//const userRep = require('./front/core/repository/user/user.repository');

// Middleware
const head = require('./back/midleware/headers.config');

// Models
// TODO provide schema when it will be raedy
const userModel = require('./back/models/user.model');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users');

// Body parser config
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Headers config
app.use(head.headerConfig);

// Endpoint configuration
restify.serve(router, userModel.UserModel, {
    name: 'users',
});

app.use(router);
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.post')
})
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.post')
})
app.listen(2000, function () {
    console.info('Server is locating on port 2000');
    console.info('to access localhost:2000/api/v1');
});
```

Ajax Request:

```
import { UserRepository } from    '../../core/repository/user/user.repository';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

class HttpExampleController {
    constructor(UserRepository) {
        this.repository = UserRepository;
        this.allUsers = [];
        this.user = {};

        this.newUser = {
                            id: 4,
                            email: "new@email.com",
                            username: "newUserName",
                            name: "newName"
                       };

        this.updatedUser = {
                            email: "updated@email.com",
                            name: "updatedUserName"
                          };

        this.getAllUsers();
    }

    getAllUsers() {
        this.repository.getAllUsers()
            .then(userList => {
                this.allUsers = userList;
            });
    }


    // Discuss if we need this method
    getUser(userId) {
        this.repository.getUser(userId)
                        .then(user => {
                            this.user = user;
                        });
    }

    createUser(user) {
        this.repository.createUser(user)
            .then(res => {
                this.allUsers.push(res);
            });
    }

    updateUser(user, data) {
        let index = _.indexOf(this.allUsers, _.find(this.allUsers, findUser => findUser._id === user._id));
        this.repository.updateUser(user._id, data)
            .then(res => {
                this.allUsers[index] = res;
            });
    }

    deleteUser(user) {
        let index = _.indexOf(this.allUsers, _.find(this.allUsers, findUser => findUser._id === user._id));
        this.repository.deleteItem(user._id)
            .then(res => _.pull(this.allUsers, res));
    }

    testFunc() {
        this.allUsers.shift();
    }
}

export { HttpExampleController };
```

Comment: try `console.log(req.body)`. You're logging a string.

Comment: it even does not logs string.

Comment: What does your ajax request on the client side look like?

Comment: just keep your username as primary key, it will throw an error if the username already exists?